# how to come back when you are reading code in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have been developing in zend studio and there is a feature I miss a lot in Xcode. When you are reading code in a main function and you want to go in a specific function to read something, you can click in the left area of your current line of code were your are, and a flag-mark appears in that line of code, so you can go anywere else in the code and it will be very easy to come back to that line of code you were before because there is a flag and you only have to click on it and you automatically go back. Does Anybody know a similar way to do this in Xcode?

Comment: There are back and forward buttons (like in a web browser) at the top of each editing pane and to the left of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature was present in earlier versions of Xcode (up to Xcode3 IIRC) and was called "Bookmarks", but it was removed since then.

You can use breakpoints (and disable them) as a workaround, even if it's not perfect. I personally prefer using other tricks, like "Open Quickly" and named tabs.

---

#### Alternate trick 1 : "Open Quickly"

One trick is to use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (or "File" menu > "Open Quickly") to quickly open a file. In the field that appears, you can type:

- The **name or parts of the name of a file**.

  - Typing `"MainViewController"` will propose to jump to the `MainViewController.h` or `MainViewController.m` file.
  - Typing `"MainVC"` will work too, as well as `"MainViewCtrl"`, as long as the order of the letters you type is the same as the full name.
  - Very handy to just type `"ContTVCell"` to open the `ContactsTableViewCell.h` file that is hidden deep in subgroups of my project for example
- Similarly, you may also type **the name or parts of the name of a symbol, especially a method name**.

  - For example, typing `tvcellforrow` will list you all the definitions of `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` it could find in your project and let to jump to the one you want
- When typing (parts of) the name of a file, **adding `:` followed by a number at the end will allow you to directly jump at the corresponding line**

  - For example, typing `mvc:50` will propose you to jump to line `50` of `MainViewController.h` or `MainViewController.m`

---

#### Another trick : using (named) tabs

Don't forget that you can open tabs in Xcode, which can be very handy in this kind of situation.

- When you are editing a file at some interesting position, you can create a new tab to browse elsewhere and go at any other place… and then go back to your first tab to find the code where you left it at the time you switched to the other tab.
- Don't forget that **you can name your tabs** (simply double-click on their title) to give them a more explicit title. You may then quite think of them as "named bookmarks" somehow
- Likewise, don't forget that you can **detach tabs in separate windows** too, if you prefer (for example to keep them around and visible on your secondary screen while you edit another part of your code)

You can even **combine this with the "Open Quickly" trick presented above**: once you made the "Open Quickly" field appear and typed something into it, instead of just validating using the <kbd>enter</kbd> key:

- use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to let Xcode present you a small widget that let you choose where you want the file to open (in the current tab, in another tab, in the assistant editor, in a dedicated window…)
- use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to open the file using the alternate navigation defined in Xcode preferences (Xcode > Preferences > Navigation > Optional Navigation). By default, the behavior when opening a file while using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is to open the file in the Assistant Editor. Personally I changed that in my Xcode preferences as I prefer to make Xcode open the file in a separate tab instead, which makes <kbd>Alt</kbd>+clic much more useful.

---

*Sure, all those tricks with "Open Quickly…" and "Tabs" do not replace the bookmarks feature that you are missing. But they are still nice alternate ways to jump quickly to any position in your code, even any specific line of any specific file in your project, wherever you are in Xcode (even without having to have the Project Navigator visible on the left part of your window), and let you have multiple editors in different tabs to go quickly back to a part of interest in your code*

Answer (score 1):

its on top of your editor i have added two pics just check them.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I know this, and the prag marks too, but its to go on the top of a funcion. If the function has 1xxxx lines of code, you need to set a point or a flag somewere to save time reading the code to get back were you were. This is not a luxury feature, but very usefull to get back instantly were you was reading...

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate to another place in Xcode, say, open a different file, or Command-click and jump to definition, you can go forward and back by swiping right or left on the trackpad with two fingers.

You can also use keyboard shortcuts: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to go forward, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to go back.

Finally, you can click triangular buttons at the top left in your edit area.

Answer (score 1):

There is a go back button at the top left of the editor!

If that is not good enough, whar I do is misuse breakpoints to set flags in my code. The breakpoint navigator thus becomes a table of flags. It isn't much but there you are.